# okhttp - execute() vs body().byteStream

Tags: okhttp, okio

When using `OkHttp`, the network request is executed in `1` or `2` in the following code:

```
            val response = client.newCall(request).execute() // (1)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val bs = response.body().byteStream() // (2)
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bs)
            } else { ... }
```

I always thought I was executed in `(1)`, in which case it makes sense to ask if the response was successful. But today I decided to implement [this official recipe](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/Progress.java) to track the progress of the file being downloaded.

Then I realised, that if I deleted the lines (`response.body().byteStream()`), the progress counter doesn't move at all. In theory, we are not downloading anything, except we are or else what does `success` mean in this scenario.

I'm sorry if this is a dummy question, I believe there's something very fundamental about networking that I'm missing here, and I would like to learn more.
I tried to understand the source code for the `Okio`library but it's a little too complex for me, I would need some reference or guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s four steps to each OkHttp call:

1. Write the request headers
2. Stream the request body, if it exists
3. Read the response headers
4. Stream the response body

When you call `execute()` OkHttp does steps 1 – 3. Further calls stream the response body. If your response body is large this allows you to start decoding the response while it's still downloading.

Comment: Thanks @Jesse! That makes a lot of sense. Two follow up questions, do I have to close the stream or okhttp does it for me? And what resources do you recommend to learn more about this subject. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, always close the response body. Best resources are the case OkHttp wiki and the HTTP specs.